# Form data to accept nested schema in Javascript

Tags: html, json, api

I have a JSON schema which i am trying to make my form tailor, but the schema has nested objects and arrays like so:

```
{
   "person": {
      "firstName":"Kay",
      "lastName":"Young"
    }
"addressDetails":[
   {
      "line1": "line1",
      "line2": "line2"
   }]
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="caseIdentifier">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="?">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="?">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="line1">Line 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="line1" name="?">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="line2">Line 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="line2" name="?">
</div>
```

JS

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

const url = url;

const formData = new FormData(this);

let object = {};

formData.forEach(function (value, key) {

    object[key] = value;

});

let json = JSON.stringify(object);

let fetchData = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: json,
    headers: <myHeaders>
}



fetch(url, fetchData)

    .then(function (response) {

        console.log(fetchData)

        return response.text();

    }).then(function (text) {

        console.log(text);

    }).catch(function (error) {

        console.error(error);

    });
});
```

How do I tailor my HTML form to match these parameters in JS? please.

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: You should provide us with the example of your solution.

Comment: I just edited it now, the name field in the html form has question mark on it and I feel that thats where I need to handle the key value pairs